# Cannot COPY from previous stage in DockerFIle

Tags: docker, nginx, mkdocs

This looks like a common issue so I checked a few SO posts but none of them solved my problem.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```yaml
# MkDocs container
FROM python:3-alpine AS build-env

RUN apk add bash

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pymdown-extensions \
&& pip install mkdocs \
&& pip install mkdocs-material \
&& pip install mkdocs-rtd-dropdown \
&& pip install mkdocs-git-revision-date-plugin \
&& pip install mkdocs-git-revision-date-localized-plugin \
&& pip install mkdocs-redirects

# executed at ~/Developer/MkDocs
RUN mkdir -p /home/mkdocs/
WORKDIR /home/mkdocs/
COPY . .
RUN mkdocs build -s
WORKDIR /

# Nginx container
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine
RUN apk add bash
EXPOSE 80

RUN cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir -p /home/mkdocs
COPY --from=build-env /home/mkdocs/site/ /home/mkdocs/
RUN mv /home/mkdocs/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/*

USER nginx:nginx
```

And here is the command to run docker:

```sh
docker run -it --name mkdocs -p 8789:80 nginx
```

Running `localhost:8789` only shows the default `nginx` homepage, not the built one of `MkDocs`. I also run `docker exec -it --user root <PID> bash` to check the directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/` but the copied files are not there.

My other checks:

- First, I'm 100% sure that the files built in the first stage works and exists
- Second, this is what completely frustrated me out. If I run the docker using `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash mkdocs:v1`, I can actually see the built MkDocs files:

```
bash-5.1$ ls /usr/share/nginx/html
404.html        50x.html        assets          index.html      search          sitemap.xml     sitemap.xml.gz
bash-5.1$
```

Comment: `docker run ... nginx` runs the standard Docker Hub Nginx image.  Do you mean to `docker run ... mkdocs:v1`?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze I knew it's a stupid error! Now it works. Thank you so much!